# function query_posts disabling current_page_menu class

Tags: categories, menus, query, query-posts

I have a header and a footer menu (they're the same: Primary Menu). When I'm on a page, wordpress adds classes like `current_page_menu`. But on pages where I use the `query_posts()` function the menus **after** this function dont have those classes added like `current_page_menu` etc.

Here is my code that is causing the bug:

```
<?php
  $title_slug = strtolower(str_replace( " ", "-" , the_title_attribute('echo=0') ) );
  $id_obj = get_category_by_slug($title_slug);
  $cat_id = $id_obj->term_id;
  query_posts( 'cat='.$cat_id.'&post_status=publish,future&paged='.get_query_var('paged') );
?>
```

This code is very useful, though. As it ensures to create a category page by adding a page and selecting the category page template instead of just a link to that category. I had to do this because my category pages need to have child pages.

I'd be greatful if anyone knows a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the `query_posts` function, this function alters the global $wp_query which the menu walker uses to check and add classes like `current_page_menu` to menu items.

A solution would be to write a new custom query and loop through that than using `query_posts`.

```
$title_slug = strtolower(str_replace( " ", "-" , the_title_attribute('echo=0') ) );
$id_obj     = get_category_by_slug($title_slug);
$cat_id     = $id_obj->term_id;
$args       = 'cat='.$cat_id.'&post_status=publish,future&paged='.get_query_var('paged');
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            //YOUR CONTENT
    <?php endwhile; ?>
        /* Restore original Post Data */
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**References:**

- [query_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/)
- [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know the walker function for the menu classes was using the global query object. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you're able to answer [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/255827/add-agenda-items-and-notifications) I asked the community as well